# Client Stub to send HTTP Requests

Tags: java, rest, web, client, jboss-arquillian

I'm a Core Java developer and only just starting to learn J2EE and have to develop a Client Test Stub that will test sending HTTP Requests and receiving Server Sent Events from a REST interface. My knowledge of REST is summed up by knowing the acronym and that's it. Can anyone point me in a "learner friendly" direction to get something up and running? So many options but being familiar with Java - I'm better off trying to keep it simple. Any ideas for a starting point for "an extreme beginner"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html). This gives you access to a nice and complete Http library with which you could start to build up all the methods (GET, POST, DELETE, PUT) to connect with your REST service.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks very much lads - appreciate it. I will create an interface to abstract the details anyway but cheers for taking time to reply :)

Answer (score 1):

[Spring RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) class could be useful. Here is simple usage guide at [official site page](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/) e.g. retrieving RESTful service response as Java-object.

```
Wrapper response = new RestTemplate().getForObject("http://any-api-url", Wrapper.class)
```

Comment: Thanks for the example :) - appreciated